# In Ember Data, how do I find only records that have been loaded?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

According to the documentation:

http://emberjs.com/guides/ember-data-lifecycle/

Ember data will automatically look to the persistent layer for a record if it's not loaded, how do I only `find` or even `findAll` records that have been loaded?

Aside from creating a non-persistent list of loaded records, and look for the record there?

Comment: New guide location if anyone 404s on the link above. http://emberjs.com/guides/models/model-lifecycle/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this via a filter:

```
App.Post.filter(function(post) { return post.get('isLoaded'); });
```

This will keep an up-to-date Array of only the `App.Post` records that have been loaded. When new records are loaded, it will automatically update (and update any DOM that is bound to it).