# Ember JS: how to use the {{#each}} helper to render only loaded children?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using the `{{#each}}` helper to iterate through the children of a parent record:

```
... parent template ...

{{#each foo in foos}}
    {{#with foo}}
        {{ partial 'foo' }}
    {{/with}}
{{/each}}
```

In a specific case, I would like to only render records that have already been loaded. I believe you can filter such records (as per [In Ember Data, how do I find only records that have been loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088094/in-ember-data-how-do-i-find-only-records-that-have-been-loaded)):

```
App.Foo.filter(function(foo) { return foo.get('isLoaded'); });
```

But how would one do that within the each helper? I created a `loaded_foos` property on the parent record, but it won't work since it is a function and not an Ember.Array.

Comment: FYI the `{{with}}` is unnecessary. `foo` is already the context.

Comment: Without `{{#with foo}}` you would need to use `{{#each foos}}`. The `in` version of `{{#each}}` doesn't alter context.

Comment: Ah. Thanks a lot, I did not know you could do `{{#each foos}}` like that and it would alter the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that within a each helper. Your approach with a property was right indeed. What did not work? It should basically look like this:

```
App.ParentRecord = Ember.Object.extend({
  loadedFoos : function(){
    this.get("foos").filter(function(foo) { return foo.get('isLoaded'); });
  }.property("foos")
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. I had loadedFoos setup as an Observer... hence the fact it did not work. I should have used a Computed Property instead as you suggested.

Comment: Actually, I spoke a little too fast. For this to work, I believe you will need to replace the filter with `App.Foo.filter(function(f) { return (f.get('isLoaded') && f.get('parent').get('id') == self.get('id')); });`. Otherwise, the `this.get("foos")` will try and load the records (and we don't want this).

Comment: Glad, it helped. I am not sure about your comment on the right code snippet without seeing the rest of the code. And i am also no ember-data expert :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the template with a conditional helper as well.

```
{{#each foos}}
  {{#if isLoaded}}
    {{partial "foo"}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Edit: The above works if you already have a mixed collection of loaded and unloaded records in an array. The OP asked how to actually get the loaded records. I would go about it this way:

```
App.Foo = DS.Model.extend();

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Foo.all();
    }
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{#each controller}}
        {{partial "foo"}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmacleod/sdUgf/) example.

Comment: This still would create a container view if specified e.g. via `{{#each controller itemViewClass="App.SomeView"}}`, though.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it will try and load from the server all the records in the association when you do `{{#each foos}}`(that's what I see in my tests). I only want to display already loaded records. I believe the only way to do this is to use what Yehuda suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14088094/in-ember-data-how-do-i-find-only-records-that-have-been-loaded.

Comment: @iStefo: If you needed a custom view, you could move it to a `{{view}}` tag inside the `{{if}}`. @PJC: I misunderstood what you were after. I agree that the link you included is the best solution.

Comment: I take it back; `App.Foo.all()` returns all known loaded records without issuing a new request to the server.